# Image resize in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

(1300, 730)
(433, 320)
(428, 320)
(428, 320)
(108, 108)
(416, 301)
(42, 42)
(307, 307)
(34, 34)
(1253, 1880)
(260, 194)
(428, 320)
(436, 322)
(1253, 1880)
(428, 320)
(285, 236)
(1253, 1880)
(259, 194)
If I have images with the above mentioned dimensions then how can I resize them to 100 img size. I have tried using tf.image.resize but it takes image tensor of 3D or 4D. How can I resize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a channel and batch dimension.

Let's make a random 2D image:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.random.uniform(shape=(40, 40), minval=0, maxval=256)
```

Let's turn this into 4D by adding the two dimensions I mentioned:

```
three_d_image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)
four_d_image = tf.expand_dims(three_d_image, axis=0)
```

Your image now has 4 dimensions:

```
four_d_image.shape
```

```
TensorShape([1, 40, 40, 1])
```

Now you can reshape it and verify its shape:

```
tf.image.resize(four_d_image, size=(100, 100)).shape
```

```
TensorShape([1, 100, 100, 1])
```